# DiscreteUniform rv with variable length

Tags: sympy

The [DiscreteUniform](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html#sympy.stats.DiscreteUniform) constructor requires an 'items' iterable containing a fixed input set. Is it possible to create a discrete uniform random variable with *variable* length? I would like to be able to do something like:

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.stats as ss

n = sp.symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)
X = ss.VariableDiscreteUniform('X', 0, n)

display(ss.E(X))        # n/2
display(ss.variance(X)) # n(n+2)/12
```

This is analogous to how the [Uniform](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html#sympy.stats.Uniform) constructor operates for creating a uniform continuous random variable.

Comment: This is not yet supported although there is an active PR working on it:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16962#issuecomment-503182584

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow that PR and test it.